# How do I stop deleted Xamarin Forms iOS resource files from being deployed to App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, resources, app-store-connect, testflight

I have let's say 5 text files in my **Xamarin Forms iOS** project under:

**Project Name** -> **Resources** -> **TextFiles** -> **File1.txt**, **File2.txt**, **File3.txt**, **File4.txt**, **File5.txt**

Upon launching my app I copy the files to a working folder via `NSBundle.GetPathsForResources()` from where I can start to use them.

```
public string GetWorkingFolder()
{
    string docs = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

    return Path.Combine(docs, "..", "Library");
}
```

For release I have decided I no longer need the last 3 files, so I removed them from the **Project Name** -> **Resources** -> **TextFiles** project folder.

This works fine when running the app on my iphone in debug mode, only **File1.txt** and **File2.txt** remain.

When I upload the app into **App Connect** though and deploy it through **TestFlight** on my device, the 5 files are still there.

I have tried the following:

- deleted the files via my app in the working **Library** folder above
- uninstalled the app
- reinstalled the app

The 5 files return, which proves they are coming from the **TestFlight** package and not from a cached Library folder.

What is going on here? Even if the files were not deleted from the **Library** folder by myself, shouldn't uninstalling the app automatically remove those folders and files? How can I remove them from my package?

Any ideas?

Comment: have you cleaned your solution, and manually deleted the bin/obj folders before building?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jason, I will try manually deleting these folders and report back on the outcome.

Comment: I manually deleted those folders but the files are still being read from Resources. Can I confirm your understanding of the folder from my `GetWorkingFolder()` method above. Am I right to assume this folder and all its contents should be deleted everytime the app is uninstalled?

Comment: yes, on iOS the folder should be deleted when you delete the app

Comment: Does that mean this could be a problem with TestFlight not properly tidying up between installs?

Comment: That seems unlikely.  I’d add some logic to check for the existence of the folder and any files when your app launches, and lo log each file it copies from Resources

Comment: I did more testing. I added a completely new file, let's say **File6.txt** directly to my Working Folder using the app during runtime, and not via compile time app Resources. I uninstalled the app, reinstalled it via TestFlight and **File6.txt** is still there. As such it does seem like the uninstall is not doing a proper cleanup job.

Comment: Can you tell me the steps to "delete the files via my app in the working Library folder above"? Did you turn on iTunes backup? The library directory (except for the Caches subdirectory) is backed up by iTunes. For more details, you can check out the official documentation:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system#application-directories

Comment: Hi Dongzhi, thanks for your reply. I simply used the .NET File.Delete on the filepath. I didn't consciously turn on iTunes backup. I don't know how to. I also did no backup or restore between uninstall and reinstall. But also if an application is deleted, wouldn't iTunes also delete related files in backup as well?

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code where you use File.WriteAllText() and File.Delete()? You can check which directories your files are saved in and try to delete your backup file. Fore more details, you may refer to this official document:https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT204215

Comment: Dongzhi, thanks for your reply, but I'm going to put a hold on this for now, as at least I know on a fresh install on a new device only the files from `Project Name -> Resources -> TextFiles` will be included. That's good enough for now. If I need more answers I'll revive this thread. Cheers